# Cannot access environment variable during jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

In my `.env` file I have a custom entry `SECRET_FILE_NAME=mysecretfile.txt`. Somewhere in my controller I need to access `mysecretfile.txt`, and I obtain its path as follows:

```php
base_path(env('SECRET_FILE_NAME'))
```

This returns the correct path:

```php
"C:\laragon\www\myproject\mysecretfile.txt"
```

However, during an AJAX POST call the result is

```php
"C:\laragon\www\myproject"
```

It turns out that `env('SECRET_FILE_NAME')` returns `"mysecretfile.txt"` during a regular POST (tested through Postman Chrome extension), but it returns `null` during AJAX POST.

**How is it possible?** Both are POST-ing to the same URL, same controller action. Is this a caching issue? I tried `php artisan config:clear` but nothing changed.

On a side note, do you think it's ok to access ENV variables directly from `.env` file? Or should I instead put them in `app/config/services.php` and access them though

```php
config('services.filenames.mysecretfile')
```

Thanks!

#### EDIT

With the help of @shalvah, I figured that putting a reference to the environment variable in `config/services.php` fixed the problem:

```php
'secret_filenames' => [
    'my_secret_file' => env('SECRET_FILE_NAME')
],
```

The entry still remains in the `.env` file: `SECRET_FILE_NAME=mysecretfile.txt`. But now I can use it as follows:

```php
config('services.secret_filenames.my_secret_file')
```

This solves my problem; however I am curious why calling `env('SECRET_FILE_NAME')` directly results in a `null` value? Is this caching issue? Also, does it make sense to store this kind of info in `services.php`?

#### EDIT 2

Just stumbled upon a [discussion on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/configcache-makes-variables-in-env-null) that might shed some light on this.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried using `getenv()` instead?

Comment: Also, try setting up the environment values in `config.php` and calling `config()` in your AJAX request instead.

Comment: Yes, `getenv()` does not work either

Comment: What about `config()`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `config.php` as there is no such file under `/config` directory. I've put the filename under services, and it worked with `config()` function automagically. This makes no sense because the standalone `env` returns `null`, but when used in `services.php` it gets the actual value... Both of them work during a non-AJAX call...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was what I meant. Glad it worked.

Comment: Thanks! At this point I am guessing that this must be a caching issue.

Comment: Maybe. Or it's just some bug